# React: How do you distribute and array of elements evenly across n rows?

Tags: arrays, reactjs

Based on screensize, I am looking to distribute an array of x items across n rows dynamically in React. I want each row as an individual div that I can manipulate separately, as I want to be able to scroll X each row individually. Ergo - no flexbox here guys ;)

[image]

Using `useEffect` I will create a state variable that determines the amount of rows to be displayed, and from that, I need a way to split an array of perhaps 50 images, evenly across this row count.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export default function Home() {

    const [rows, setRows] = useState(2)


    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
    // 50 pixels standard grid element width
    const gridWidth = 50;

    // Temporary tiles array
    const tiles: [{ color: string, width: number }?] = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
        tiles.push({
            color: getRandomColor(),
            width: gridWidth * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1)
        })
    }

    console.log(tiles);

    const handleScroll = (e: React.WheelEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e.deltaX)
    };
    // Splice array into X rows depending on screen height

    const renderTiles = (i: number) => {
        let j = 1 + i;
        for (let index = 0; index < tiles.length; index += j) {
            return <div className="tile" style={{ width: tiles[index]?.width, backgroundColor: tiles[index]?.color }}></div>
        }
    }

    const renderRows = () => {
        for (let index = 1; index < rows; index++) {
            return <div className="row" onWheel={handleScroll}>{renderTiles(index)}</div>
        }
    }

    return (
        <div id="wrapper">
            {renderRows()}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: So you want to keep creating new rows until it matches the height of the screen? then keep appending items into the rows once  you know how many rows there are? Does this HAVE to be done in react or can it be done in css with grid? Is each element the same height?

Comment: All items will maintain the height of the rows.. The react part is mainly fact that I use `useEffect` and that each of the items in the array shall output a component...

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue.. I was for looping when not possible for JSX returns. This script is the one working..

```
export default function Home() {

    const [rows, setRows] = useState(3)


    function getRandomColor() {
        var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
        var color = '#';
        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
        }
        return color;
    }
    // 50 pixels standard grid element width
    const gridWidth = 50;

    // Temporary tiles array
    const tiles: [{ color: string, width: number }?] = [];
    for (let index = 0; index < 50; index++) {
        tiles.push({
            color: getRandomColor(),
            width: gridWidth * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1)
        })
    }

    const handleScroll = (e: React.WheelEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // console.log(e.deltaX)
    };
    // Splice array into X rows depending on screen height

    const renderTiles = (i: number) => {
        const rowTiles = [];
        let j = 1 + i;
        for (let index = j; index < tiles.length; index += rows) {
            rowTiles.push(<div key={index + j + "tile"} className="tile" style={{ width: tiles[index]?.width, backgroundColor: tiles[index]?.color }}></div>)
        }
        return rowTiles;
    }

    const renderRows = () => {
        const gridRows = []
        for (let index = 0; index < rows; index++) {
            gridRows.push(<div key={index + "row"} className="row" onWheel={handleScroll}>{renderTiles(index)}</div>);
        }
        return gridRows
    }

    return (
        <div id="wrapper">
            {renderRows().map(r => { console.log('hi'); return r; })}
        </div>
    )
}
```